# Cannot load xib from framework

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, xcframework

I can't seem to load a nib file in the framework I have created. The thing is I worked on it for more than a month and it was working fine. I opened it again today after 2 weeks and it's just crashing. I couldn't believe it.

I have created a tiny sample [project](https://github.com/rishabdutta/NibFramework) where I am able to reproduce the issue.

To get the Bundle I am using

```
let bundle = Bundle(identifier: "com.nibFramework.NibFramework")
```

This is returning nil btw.

So I tried

```
let bundle = Bundle(for: MyNib.self)
```

Using the nib

```
let nib = UINib(nibName: "\(MyNib.self)", bundle: bundle)
let array = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)
```

And this is crashing on `instantiate`.

```
Error
2021-11-23 23:55:52.381944+0530 NibApp[7432:2147418] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7817FD25-54BC-4920-AC67-49D246D28794/NibApp.app> (loaded)' with name 'MyNib''
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1827f904c 0x19ae6df54 0x182850180 0x18513f338 0x1040b0d9c 0x1040af164 0x1040af1c0 0x184db415c 0x184db6c10 0x184d896a4 0x184ecc4d8 0x184e21da0 0x184eb8f84 0x184ed3598 0x184c594a0 0x184f5f584 0x185260400 0x184f61c80 0x184ea10b4 0x1942f0e20 0x194316cdc 0x1942d16b4 0x1942d2cf4 0x10441e3b4 0x104421e70 0x1942d2f94 0x1942d23d4 0x1942d69e4 0x18281b020 0x18282bce0 0x182766054 0x18276b7f4 0x18277f3b8 0x19e10f38c 0x18511f6a8 0x184e9e7f4 0x199e98184 0x1040afcb8 0x1040afc40 0x1040afd38 0x104325a24)
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
dyld4 config: DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/system/introspection DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Developer/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/Developer/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib:/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDDISupport.framework/libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7817FD25-54BC-4920-AC67-49D246D28794/NibApp.app> (loaded)' with name 'MyNib''
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I am using Xcode 13.1. The Mach-O Type of this framework is set to `Static Library`.

Pretty sure I am missing some simple thing. Just can't figure out what. Thanks for your help.

Comment: you did some good approach first.. try to see what Bundle outputs with the standard paths it offers. When the nib is in the framework, check what `NSString *privatePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] privateFrameworksPath];` sorry objc, outputs. Because framework stuff does not liv in the resources folder, so standard lookup does not work as is.

Comment: @OlSen Running that code gived me `/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/69CA5508-5C73-4309-BEC8-91C958069808/NibApp.app/Frameworks
`.  So I use `let bundle = Bundle(path: path)` but it's still crashing.

Comment: May be use SPM? With SPM you will have `Bundle.module` for module resources

Answer (score 0):

Any Framework Bundle created with Xcodes Template will have a structure that you can rely on when looking for content packed in it.

Nib/Xib files are Resources, so with compiling they end up being copied into the according subfolder of the created Bundle (Framework in this case).
So you should be able to construct the needed Resources Folder manually.

```
NSString *privateFWPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] privateFrameworksPath];
NSString *nibPath = [privateFWPath stringByAppendingString:@"/NibFramework.framework/Versions/A/Resources/MyNib"];
```

another way is to ask the class for its bundle and construct the frameworks Resources folder to reach the nib.

```
[NSBundle bundleForClass:MyNib.class];
```

PS: guessing *MyNib.self* is not a class, it is an object.
A way to check if the nib/xib ended up in the framework is to climb thru the folder structure with your desktops Finder.app. Your App will have a Frameworks folder, in there a **NibFramework.framework** and in this some link to Resources deeper into the structure or directly a **Versions** folder, subfolder **A** in which a **Resources** folder should be found and the nib will reside in. To do this you will compile first of course and then select the Product in your Xcode project, right click > show in Finder and then right click > Show Contents.

Hint: Asking Bundle for contents has a side effect when the input given results in (nil) or (null), it usually returns the mainBundle then.
Reminder: nib/xib/storyboard files do not reside in the root folder of a bundle.